# Is NSFetchedResultController performFetch thread safe?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I'm working with NSManagedObjectContext in multithreads.
I wonder if it request lock before call NSFetchedResultController performFetch.

Shall I do this

```
[moc lock];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![fetchedResultsController_ performFetch:&error]) {
    //TODO: add fetch error handler        
} 
[moc unlock];
```

Or just

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![fetchedResultsController_ performFetch:&error]) {
    //TODO: add fetch error handler        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `fetchedResultsController` is shared across multiple threads, then not only must you lock the managed object context before performing the fetch, but it **must also be locked while you use any object returned by that fetch**. Naturally, that's not a very easy thing to guarantee, and tends to limit the benefits of doing things on mulitple threads in the first place.

Applications using Core Data are strongly encouraged to use one managed object context per thread. See [Concurrency with Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) for more information.

Comment: I do not share fetchedResultsController, but I do share the NSManagedObjectedContext.

I you mean I do have to lock the NSManagedObjectContext?

Comment: Yes. If the managed object context is shared, then any time you interact with the context OR ANY OBJECT THAT WAS FETCHED FROM IT, you must lock the context. If you don't, then changes to those managed objects may not be saved correctly.